# wpbakery- anchor wont wrap around iframe

Tags: wordpress, video

I'm having an issue with wpbakery. I'm trying to add this code to one of the pages of my website. https://jsfiddle.net/mx5h59rz/84/

```
<a href="http://tumblr.com" target="_blank" class="linkwrap">
 <div class="blocker"></div>
 <iframe width="420" height="315" 
 src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/258549989?background=1" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

css

```
.linkwrap { position:relative; display:inline-block; }
.blocker { position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:1; 
background:rgba(255,0,0,0.0);  }
.linkwrap iframe { z-index: 2; }
```

The problem when I put the code in a textbox element. the anchor that wraps around always goes away.

Can anyone answer me why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 <div class="blocker"></div>
 <iframe width="420" height="315" 
 src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/258549989?background=1" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <a href="http://tumblr.com" target="_blank" class="linkwrap">
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. Since im using wordpress with visual composer i should of used the raw html element.